# Spring MVC with Jaxb2Marshaller failing on 2013 dates

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jaxb2

I have a Spring MVC project that accepts XML input via a the PUT method. One of the elements in the XML is a `dateTime`. I am using a `Jaxb2Marshaller` to unmarshal the XML into a bean. I have a unit test that runs against the webapp running on a server.

When I send in a timestamp using `new GregorianCalendar(2012, 01, 02)` everything works well and my application receives the Object.

However, if I update my test to use `new GregorianCalendar(2013, 01, 02)` that field in the Object is returned as `null`.

Notice that the only difference is the year, 2012 vs 2013. I do not see any error messages in the application log, localhost or catalina.out.

Thoughts?

Edit: Additional Info...

I am using the `DataTypeConverter` to convert from `dateTime` to `Calendar`. So my schema has the following (and I am using XJC to convert the schema to Java classes).

```
<annotation><appinfo><jaxb:globalBinding>
      <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.Calendar" xmlType="dateTime"
          parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDate"
          printMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.pringDate"/>
</jaxb:globalBinding></appinfo></annotation>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got rid of the mapping to `Calendar` and allowed XJC to produce the Java classes with `XMLGregorianCalendar`. This seemed to resolve the issue. Still seems strange so am open to insight.